# MongoDB 'upsert' from Grails

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, upsert

I'm trying to implement a simple "insert or update" (so-called 'upsert') method in Grails / GORM / mongodb plug-in / MongoDB.

The approach I used with Hibernate (using merge) fails with a duplicate key error. I presume perhaps merge() isn't a supported operation in mongodb GORM, and tried to get to the native upsert method through GMongo.

I finally have a version that works (as posted below), but it is probably not the best way, as adding any fields to the object being saved will break the code silently.

```
 public void upsertPrefix(p) {
    def o = new BasicDBObject()
    o.put("_id", p.id)
    o.put("someValue", p.someValue)
    o.put("otherValue", p.otherValue)

    // DBObject o = p as DBObject // No signature of method: mypackage.Prefix.keySet() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

    db.prefix.update([_id : p.id], o, true, false)
    // I actually would want to pass p instead of o here, but that fails with:
    // No signature of method: com.gmongo.internal.DBCollectionPatcher$__clinit__closure2.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList) values: [[[_id:keyvalue], mypackage.Prefix : keyvalue, ...]]


    /* All of these other more "Hibernatesque" approaches fail:
    def existing = Prefix.get(p.id)
    if (existing != null) {
        p.merge(flush:true) // E11000 duplicate key error
        // existing.merge(p) // Invocation failed: Message: null
        // Prefix.merge(p) // Invocation failed: Message: null

    } else {
        p.save(flush:true)
    } 
    */
}
```

I guess I could introduce another POJO-DbObject mapping framework to the mix, but that would complicate things even more, duplicate what GORM is already doing and may introduce additional meta-data.

Any ideas how to solve this in the simplest fashion?

Edit #1: I now tried something else:

```
    def existing = Prefix.get(p.id)
    if (existing != null) {
//      existing.properties = p.properties // E11000 duplicate key error...
        existing.someValue = p.someValue    
        existing.otherValue = p.otherValue  
        existing.save(flush:true)
    } else {
        p.save(flush:true)
    }
```

Once again the non-commented version works, but is not well maintainable. The commented version which I'd like to make work fails.

Edit #2:

**Version which works**:

```
public void upsertPrefix(p) {
    def o = new BasicDBObject()

    p.properties.each {
        if (! (it.key in ['dbo'])) {
            o[it.key] = p.properties[it.key]
        }
    } 
    o['_id'] = p.id

    db.prefix.update([_id : p.id], o, true, false)
}
```

Version which never seems to insert anything:

```
def upsertPrefix(Prefix updatedPrefix) {
     Prefix existingPrefix = Prefix.findOrCreateById(updatedPrefix.id)
     updatedPrefix.properties.each { prop ->
          if (! prop.key in ['dbo', 'id']) { // You don't want to re-set the id, and dbo is r/o
                existingPrefix.properties[prop.key] = prop.value
          }
    }
    existingPrefix.save() // Never seems to insert anything
}
```

Version which still fails with duplicate key error:

```
def upsertPrefix(p) {
    def existing = Prefix.get(p.id)
    if (existing != null) {
        p.properties.each { prop ->
            print prop.key
            if (! prop.key in ['dbo', 'id']) { 
                existingPrefix.properties[prop.key] = prop.value
            }
        }
        existing.save(flush:true) // Still fails with duplicate key error
    } else {
        p.save(flush:true)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Mongo, but have you tried `findOrCreateBy*()` or `findOrSaveBy*()` methods? Those should let you get either a new instance, or an existing one by `Id` and you can the apply your values.

Comment: Actually, getting the new or existing instance isn't the problem, it is applying the values without listing all the attributes (as there could be very many).

Comment: Actually, it should be noted that the version I've posted above doesn't work with embedded objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have either an updated version of the object, or a map of the properties you need to update with their new values, you could loop over those and apply the updates for each property.

Something like this:

```
def upsert(Prefix updatedPrefix) {
    Prefix existingPrefix = Prefix .findOrCreateById(updatedPrefix.id)
    updatedPrefix.properties.each { prop ->
        if (prop.key != 'id') { // You don't want to re-set the id
            existingPrefix.properties[prop.key] = prop.value
        }
    }
    existingPrefix.save()
}
```

How to exclude updating the ID may not be quite correct, so you might have to play with it a bit. You also might consider only updating a property if it's corresponding new value is different from the existing one, but that's essentially just an optimization.

If you have a map, you might also consider doing the update the way the default controller scaffolding does:

```
prefixInstance.properties = params
```

Comment: I did three slightly different approaches based on this idea (see above in Edit #2) and one of them worked. The other two still fail though.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has native support for upsert. See the [findAndModify Command](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command) with upsert parameter true.

Comment: Yes, but I'm afraid it doesn't provide any advantage in this case to the native update method I'm already invoking.